# java JAR file behaves differently than .class file

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jar

I created a runnable .jar file using eclipse, but the program doesn't work so well. However, when i run the .class file from the terminal, it works perfectly.
Any ideas of why this happens?

Comment: Please provide more details to explain how it "doesn't work so well".

Comment: sorry about that, it's my first time here :)
The program is a game with simple graphics created using swing.
At the end of the game the user is asked if he wants to play again, and it should reset all the variables, and recreate all of the components of the game( buttons, labels,..). This works without any problems when run from the terminal,but when i run it from the JAR file, usually it just recreates the components, but doesn't reset the variables.
Sorry if my english isn't ok, it's not my native language :)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse using its own environment such as Java version jars etc. which is not the same as your project configuration. If you synchronize your Eclipse with your ant/pow settings it should work the same way.